# Short story where scientist creates and then unsuccessfully tries to destroy miniature civilisation in space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have had a good search and haven't been able to identify a story I read in the 80's or early 90's in a Russian sci-fi anthology. I'm pretty sure it was a translation from English. It is NOT "The Microcosmic God", though there is a similarity.

A policeman investigates an impenetrable dome that has suddenly encased a scientific laboratory. Everyone inside seems to have suffocated. Eventually the story reveals that a scientist (or maybe two scientists) undertook an experiment. They launched a satellite containing a mini solar system into space. Over time, a mini civilisation evolved in this micro world orbiting earth. Being small, they live, think and evolve much faster than humans. The scientist(s) become worried about the tiny world out-evolving earth and humans. The scientist(s) decide to end the experiment and fire off a rocket that should destroy the micro world. While it only takes a few hours for the rocket to reach the micro world, that is days in the time of the microworld. The microcivilization manages to deflect/defend the rocket strike. They respond with a weapon of their own, which targets the source of the rocket and covers the area in an impenetrable dome. Having figured it out, the policeman decides to not tell anyone.

Comment: It’s not the answer, so this is a comment, but the premise is similar to the 1958 short novel _Edge of Time_ by David Grinnell (a pseudonym for Donald A Wollheim).

Comment: Yes, typo sorry. Should read 80's.

Comment: Yes, Edge of Time is also somewhat similar, but not it. I'm starting to think it may have been an original written in Russian. Will try to find it in the Russian-speaking web.

Answer (score 14):

I managed to find it in the Russian internet. The book is called Alexey Alexeyev's Mistake. It's a Soviet sci-fi novella written in 1961. Original text can be found here. https://knijky.ru/books/oshibka-alekseya-alekseeva

Comment: Awesome! Please don't forget to come back tomorrow and accept your answer!

Comment: I'm not getting an option to accept for some reason.